# SQL Joins with varying rows? Attempting to find proper query for unequal (non-1-to-1) results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**Does mysql has a way of returning multiple row structures in one multi-tiered object, instead of the usual practice of combining rows?**

I'm attempting to retrieve all necessary product info in one query, instead of running multiple queries.

Two tables (wp_3_posts, and wp_ss_products) have  a one-to-one correspondence making one row combined.

However I decided to get a little "greedy" and *attempt to get all relevant product info in one query*, but obviously this results in multiple rows with redundant info. Perhaps I've missed something in mysqlsql education, but I'm wondering this:

So how is this problem solved?

Here is an example query:

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_ss_products

INNER JOIN wp_ss_product_meta
ON wp_ss_products.object_id = wp_ss_product_meta.object_id

INNER JOIN wp_ss_product_options 
ON wp_ss_products.object_id = wp_ss_product_options.object_id

INNER JOIN wp_3_posts 
ON wp_ss_products.post_id = wp_3_posts.ID

WHERE wp_ss_products.object_id =14
```

And of course this returns a very foolish looking result:

```
14  0   1783    3   testing again           1   0   1   cart_Item   14  some_key    this is some random value   0   1   14  size_small  4200x4200px 20.0000 1783    1   2014-05-22 01:53:00 2014-05-22 01:53:00     testing again       inherit open    open        1782-revision-v1            2014-05-25 00:03:07 2014-05-25 00:03:07     1782    http://localhost/symbiostock3/superstock/2014/05/22/1782-revision-v1/   0   revision        0
14  0   1783    3   testing again           1   0   2   cart_Item   14  random_other_key    2   0   1   14  size_small  4200x4200px 20.0000 1783    1   2014-05-22 01:53:00 2014-05-22 01:53:00     testing again       inherit open    open        1782-revision-v1            2014-05-25 00:03:07 2014-05-25 00:03:07     1782    http://localhost/symbiostock3/superstock/2014/05/22/1782-revision-v1/   0   revision        0
14  0   1783    3   testing again           1   0   3   cart_Item   14  size_x  1400    0   1
```

...and so on.

So minding database and query efficiency, what is the standard way to do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [group_concat()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to return a delimited string (which you can turn into an array very easily in PHP) of the common data.

```
select 
    id, 
    group_concat(someColumn SEPARATOR ',') as someColumn
from
    yourTable
where
    someThings=42
group by
    id
```

Then in your code, you can explode that column into an array:

```
$myArra=explode(',', $row['someColumn']);
```

You will need to use a `group by` for this to work however, so get rid of the `select * ...` in your query :)

Comment: To my mind, there is no problem the solution for which is GROUP_CONCAT ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the good response. I'll experiment with this right away and mark yours as the answer. I've never heard of GROUP_CONCAT. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Strawberry I present that very problem in [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23850877/sql-joins-with-varying-rows-attempting-to-find-proper-query-for-unequal-non-1) :P

Comment: ...by taking a fairly useful array and turning it into a fairly useless string!

Comment: @Strawberry You still get the array that is the recordset, you just get a string in that recordset that can be modified into another array as needed - or left as is where and array isn't needed. I haven't used this mysql function that I can recall, but it is there, and it seems to be exactly what the OP is looking for. Just saying :)